# Sql Merge multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help for a T-SQL statement.

I have a table with the following example data:

```
id fistname lastname phone1 phone2 phone3
------------------------------------------
01      Joe     Test  12345 
02      Joe     Test         45678
03      Max    Smith  12345
04      Max    Smith  45678
```

Now I would like to have this result:

```
Joe  Test 12345 45678
Max Smith 12345
Max Smith 45678
```

So only rows are going to merge that have the same name and no difference in the phone numbers in the specific column.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try something? Here's a tip: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: In the row with ID 02, is phone1 NULL or is it an empty string? You said "no difference", but it is obviously different from '12345'. And - for a complete sql statement - what is the name of this table? And should column "phone3" be handled too somehow?

Comment: Okay I think I should give some backround informations. The table consists of costumers and suppliers. 
I want to filter out duplicates and merge them but there could be a supplier and a costumer with both the same name but with a different telephone number. (Max Joe in my example). They should be in 2 seperate lines.

Answer (score 3):

So, as you see, the picture below shows the correct query and result. But remember that if there are multiple phones, you will lost data).

[image]

I suggest you to change the table, following the idea of the example below. Here we have a two tables. One for save contact names and another for save phone numbers of contacts.

[image]

Comment: out of interest, what client is this you're using?

Comment: You should at least make your "reformed" example the same as OP's by adding 2 `Max Smith`s and giving them different phones. That way you can do a standard left join to show how much easier it is to work with the data when properly designed.

Comment: also out of topic - what SQL client is this please? Or what modifications, it looks awesome! Thank you, I Am givin you thumb up ;-)

Comment: I AM using MySQL with MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the way your data is stored is *really* bad. If you plan on storing a finite amount of data, then storing them all on one line is arguably fine. Otherwise, when the data is varying a lot, using a table with various entries for the various phones is preferable. And in every case, you should identify the person with an id, not a `firstname`+`lastname`+combination of 3phones.

With that out of the way, you simply have to attribute an id to each individual and from there `group by id` :

```
select MIN(id), firstname, lastname, MAX(phone1), MAX(phone2), max(phone3)
from(
  select *, 
  (
     SELECT count(CASE WHEN t2.phone1!='' THEN 1 END) 
     FROM INSERT_TABLE_NAME t2 where t2.id<=t1.id
  ) AS blkno
  from INSERT_TABLE_NAME t1
) X
GROUP BY firstname, lastname, blkno;
```

Answer (score 1):

Even this could not be the answer, but your query should like below,

```
SELECT fistname, lastname, MAX(phone1) phone1, MAX(phone2) phone2, MAX(phone3) phone3
FROM TableName
GROUP BY fistname, lastname
ORDER BY fistname
```

You can see the result below,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by Group by columns (assuming the empty space as `NULL`).

```
select firstname,lastname,phone1,phone2,phone3 from tablename
group by firstname,lastname,phone1,phone2,phone3
```

Comment: Isn't this quert exactly the same as `Select * from tablename`?

Comment: Yes, this does not give the desired result.

Comment: @JulienBlanchard If its select * from tablename, then we can not group it by the column id, as its values are different,so the rows wouldn't group.

Comment: @BhanuChandra Yeah, I actually realized that after posting. The actual comparison would be `SELECT DISTINCT firstname, lastname, phone1, phone2, phone3`, which is still not an answer to OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your table is named `Contacts` and your

> no difference in the phone numbers in the specific column

actually means that `phone1` in the following rows is NULL and that `phone3` is not relevant in your question, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.fistname, A.lastname, A.phone1, B.phone2
FROM Contacts as A
LEFT JOIN Contacts as B ON (
  A.fistname = B.fistname AND 
  A.lastname = B.lastname AND 
  B.phone1 IS NULL)
WHERE NOT A.phone1 IS NULL
```

What is not clear from your question: do you just want to select the merged rows or do you want to update the table with the merge result?

[EDIT]: `LEFT JOIN`instead of `INNER JOIN` and added the `WHERE` clause.